# simple T-sql query

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

[image]

From the above sample data, i want to write a query that will return SalesAmount as 0.0 if ExpRow value = 1 and return ExpenseAmount as 0.0 if ExpRow value = 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is exactly what you are after but...

```
SELECT CASE([ExpRow]) WHEN 1 THEN 0 ELSE SalesAmount END AS 'SalesAmount',
       CASE([ExpRow]) WHEN 2 THEN 0 ELSE ExpenseAmount END AS 'ExpenseAmount'
FROM [YOUR_TABLE]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    ExpRow,
    ExpenseDate,
    CASE WHEN ExpRow = 2 THEN 0 ELSE ExpenseAmount END AS ExpenseAmount,
    CASE WHEN ExpRow = 1 THEN 0 ELSE SalesAmount END AS SalesAmount
FROM
    Table
```